# Prefab Light Probes

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I'm using DunGen to generate a german bunker for mobile in Unity3D 2018.3.0, so I have all the prefabs light mapped and each has a light probe, see picture.

Then I generate a level with DuGen using the pre baked prefabs, the level lighting looks good and each prefabs light prob group connects, so far all good.

Now my problem is baking the light probes data, I've been searching for this answer for a while but it looks as though this is not possible, then if so whats the point of being able to bake prefab light maps and not being able to use their light probe data ?

I've heard about using light volumes at runtime but cant find any information about using those ether.

Thanks.

EDIT - someone point me to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=D7LjsabD4V4

[image]